# a Textfiled does not use functions on props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Doesn't a TextField recognise functions of props?

This is a class component that takes a prop.
the prop includes a function. it is recognised out of text field. However 
When it in Textfield , "onChange" and onClick are unable to find textInput: (text: string).

```
export type props = {
    kind: 'Test'
    textInput: (text: string) => void  
}

export class KlassComponent extends Component<props, {}> {

    render() {
        switch (this.props.kind) {
            case 'Test':
                return (
                    <TextField
                onChange = { (e) => this.props.textInput(e.target.value)
                    />
        }
    }
}
```

Property 'textInput' does not exist on type '(Readonly<{ kind: "Test";

Comment: Can you print `this.props` ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have an error in the `onChange` o the `<TextField />` because you are missing a `}` closing bracket, then you'll have to check if you are getting the `textInput` prop (If not, you're setting the default value that won't handle your event).

```
export type props = {
    kind: 'Test'
    textInput: (text: string) => void  
}

export class KlassComponent extends Component<props, {}> {
    const { kind, textInput } = this.props;

    render() {
        switch (.kind) {
            case 'Test':
                return (
                    <TextField
                      onChange={e => textInput(e.target.value)}
                    />
        }
    }
}
```